# Logitech K480 Logitech Buetooth Keyboard connection

Tags: bluetooth

the rasberry pi 4 does not see the bluetooth K480 Logitech keyboard.The logitech k480 KB is a multi device kb,it has a switch to switch between 3 devices.Am using number 1.Its a new kb and has never been used before.
I am running the Linux Kernel 5.4 LTS,from the url below:
https://9to5linux.com/raspberry-pi-os-is-now-powered-by-linux-kernel-5-4-lts

Any help would be appreciated,as i do not know anything about linux or the rasberry pi

thanks

Comment: Kernel version is irrelevant - what OS? You just need to pair following the Logitec instructions.

Comment: the device is faulty,it for a return now.thanks for reading